# How will retroactive reputation gain affect the user graph?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-graph

It's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) that Stack Overflow community and Stack Exchange will receive reputation retroactively based on asked questions in the past.

> We’re recalculating reputation for every Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange individual based on this change. Every question upvote earned in the past will earn a value of ten reputation points retroactively.

**What's not clear to me:**

In the reputation graph, (that can be found in the profile) will there be a one time bonus for all the gained reputation or the graph will get redrawn according to the user's new reputation?

Comment: The gain is *retroactive* -- it will appear as if you always had earned that rep. History will be rewritten, *we've always been at war with Eastasia*-style.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reputation has already been recalculated for Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) and I just gained around 400 rep thanks to that.

From what I can see, the graph is indeed recalculated (since I don't see a big bump on my "today point" in the graph).

Comment: wow I went from 10kish to 17k here. apparently i'm good at asking questions :)

Comment: It can also stand for Mathematics Stack Exchange, so to make your posts clear, I'd recommend using the full name or the shorthand "Meta.SE".

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog Oh, I never thought about that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @enderland: Same happened for me over at Aviation.SE (same reason).

Comment: OTOH, you can now get the Yearling badge retroactively. Looking at my graph, I was awarded my Yearling badge on Arqade for 2018 (?) just a few minutes ago (awarded "15 minutes ago"). I have 519 rep *now* and the last time I had sub-419 was early 2018 where I gained a cliff-face of ~65 reputation all at once (with another 30 in the following weeks). Similar cliff-face on Physics SE (again, about 90 rep), likely as the result of a question I asked in 2017 (+5 rep, nudging the 2018 "gain 100" over the hurdle, just).

Comment: @Draco18s I just got 18 yearling badges. lol