# Will I know how much reputation I gained from the change in question rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[So question upvotes will now be worth 10 points](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) and will be retroactively applied.

I know that the [rep-cap will still apply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338119/regarding-the-recalc-in-question-rep-increase-what-happens-due-to-the-cap) when this takes place. I know that it will [appear as if I always had this rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338128/how-will-retroactively-reputation-gain-affect-the-user-graph).

But, if I do not document how much rep I had on a particular site prior to the change taking place and compare it to my recalculated rep, is there a way to know how much rep I gained due to the new system?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'd have to have memorized your prior rep. You may be able to get an *approximation* by visiting the reputation league page in this hour, as that's not updated until UTC 0:00 (4.5 hours from now).

Comment: Not automagically, you'll need a query or to manually calculate it. Because it's retroactive, there won't be an entry in the reputation history.

Comment: Something something wayback machine? Maybe? Better write down all your network reputations now before they roll it out for everything...

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog I noticed it changed here but not other sites yet, but i was able to use your suggestion and look at the league board.

Comment: Make a SEDE query and look at question votes. It'll be slightly off because of the weekly update rate, but it's at least an estimation

Comment: Is it possible to make a SEDE query to calculate rep under the old rules?  I would think the powers that be would find this useful to examine the impact of the change, in addition to useful for curious users.

Comment: @ScottSeidman it takes some time, but it's doable (see my answer below). It's even possible to determine [which sites got another #1 user because of the change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338800/295232).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1151034/reputation-gained-by-2019-11-13-change) which tries to measure this. It works as follows: it lists (almost<sup>*</sup>) all reputation events which are affected by the daily reputation limit: up- and downvotes received to both questions and answer, and approved suggested edits. It stores these both for the old rules (`OldReputation`) and the new rules (`NewReputation`). It then calculates how much reputation they would've given under the old rules:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(OldReputation) > 200 THEN 200 ELSE SUM(OldReputation) END)
```

and compares that with the same calculation for the new rules. When I [run it for my own account on Meta Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1151034/reputation-gained-by-2019-11-13-change) you see that I gained about 7000 reputation:

[image]

which is consistent with my own observation (I went from about 91k to about 98k that day). To run it for your own user account, use the site switcher to select the correct site, and enter your UserId which you can find in the URL of your profile page (or use my [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8136/34061) to have it filled automatically).

There's a [network-wide version of the SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1158336/reputation-gained-by-2019-11-13-change-network-wide) but it times out for users with a lot of posts like me.

<sup>*</sup><sub>: downvotes *given* on answer cost 1 reputation and affect the daily reputation cap. If there's a day you didn't reach the cap under the old rules, but the new rules changed that, and you spent some reputation on downvoting answers that day, you might have gained a few more reputation points because of the rule change than this query indicates. Or a few points less perhaps, I'm not fully awake yet. Similarly, the exact sequence of down- and upvotes at the end of the UTC day might make a difference a SEDE query can't account for, because [vote dates are truncated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/933/295232). That feature, and since the rule change went live gradually on November 13th, I've decided to count *all* votes on November 13th, even though they might have been cast *after* the rule change went live. There's another rule the query can't account for and which might influence the result in both ways: you retain reputation for [deleted posts older than 60 days and a score of +3 or higher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124799/295232) but they don't show up in SEDE.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Not without some effort on your side. It's a retroactive calculation that doesn't show up on the reputation page.

You can approximate by counting your question scores. It will be imprecise if you've got contested questions. In that case you'll need to look for the actual up votes. Depending how many mortarboard days you have there's the cap involved.

Since you are wondering now it's certainly easier to just take a snapshot of your user profile by noting down the rep.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm curious about the change so I am definitely jotting down my current rep on all active sites.

Comment: Good grief... I got 10,861 out of this!

Comment: This doesn't really give a good measure since also accepted answers give scores. Mine went from 341 to 541 (+200) and there are no answers with upvotes.

Comment: @aze45sq6d answers are not affected by the change, so this answer is a really good measure

Comment: I mean accepted answers on your own question gives you extra rep, so you should do a different calculation for questions without an accepter answer and with one

Comment: @aze45sq6d there was no change in accepted answer reputation. The question is about delta reputation so that doesn't matter.