# Which users gained the most reputation by the "Rewarding the Question Askers" change?

Tags: support, reputation, questions, up-votes

Since November 13th, [upvotes to questions are now worth 10 reputation instead of 5 reputation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). This has led to [some sites in the network getting a new top user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338800/295232). It's possible to see (approximately) [how much reputation you gained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338926/295232) because of the change; which users gained the *most* reputation because of it?

Comment: It's quite hard to grasp, why someone downvoted this useful, _on-topic_, well researched and self answered question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed. Why is everybody so picky these days? I swear *anything* I post gets immediately downvoted, no matter how quality it is.

Comment: @connectyourcharger: Meta has always been like that, though. It is sad. But it will soon come to an end. Which is sad too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1151321/which-users-gained-the-most-reputation-by-the-2019-11-13-change?numberOfHits=100) is a SEDE query to find this out. On Stack Overflow, some users managed to gain more than 100,000 reputation (left). On other sites, the numbers are lower: [here on Meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1151321/which-users-gained-the-most-reputation-by-the-2019-11-13-change?numberOfHits=100) the record is 33k (middle), and the highest non-Stack Overflow example I could find was [41k on Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1151321/which-users-gained-the-most-reputation-by-the-2019-11-13-change?numberOfHits=100) (right).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Breaking News: SE runs out of swag due to unanticipated side-effect of reputation re-calc causing many users to qualify for the 100K-swag package ...

Comment: Except that they paused sending it already while searching for a new swag provider ...

Comment: They already have a new provider

Comment: They do? I didn't get a mail a couple of days ago when I reached 100k ...

Comment: I know a user who already got some swag: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3249/1674