# Is there anywhere I can see my old school reputation score?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm curious as to what my old school reputation score would be on some Stack Exchange sites. Is there anywhere that I can see what my old school reputation score would be? For a period of time it looked like Area 51 had not updated and you could see everyone's reputations based off of the old rules, but that looks like it has  been fixed now.

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify - 5 points for a question upvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've modified a SEDE query I wrote to [measure reputation gain because of the change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338926/295232), and you can run it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/chinese/query/1236883/old-school-reputation-https-meta-stackexchange-com-q-347686-295232?UserId=295232).

[image]

There's a site switcher to run it on other sites as well; it'll need your user ID on that site.